# Process to Open Multiple Vector Tools at one time

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I don't even really know how to ask this question correctly, but I have a process that I am doing which requires quite a few steps of opening a vector tool, running it, taking those results and running another vector tool on thae result and so on.  Is there a way to pull all this together, like create a dash board with all of the tools opened up with on click.

I created a video to show what I am doing:  [Video to my process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uewfSK-ZVjY)

If I can just get some terms to search, maybe I could work on a solution, at this point I just don't even know what to ask for.

Comment: Have a look into the [model designer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html)